# Android get wifi activity

Tags: android, wifi

I'm trying to find out from my application if the wifi is currently being used;
as in not just connected, but something is actually downloading or uploading at the moment.
Android (4.0+) seems to be aware of this since the wifi icon changes when data is being transferred. Any way for me to access this information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found the TrafficStats class. Don't know how reliable this is but here's my code:

```
boolean isWifiInUse;
long lastTx,lastRx;
Runnable TestWifi = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        long cRx = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
        long cTx = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        if (cTx - lastTx != 0 || cRx - lastRx != 0)
        {
            if (!isWifiInUse)
                isWifiInUse = true;

        }
        else if (isWifiInUse)
        {
            isWifiInUse = false;
            //ShowToast("Data no longer in use");
        }
        lastRx = cRx;
        lastTx = cTx;
        hand.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps someone.